# rsync creates folder instead of loading files

Tags: ssh, rsync

I want to use this command

```
~/tools/app$ rsync -avze ssh user@server:src/app/* .
```

to load all files from remote folder `src/app` into my local folder `tools/app`. But instead, rsync creates a new folder `tools/app/app` and puts the files there.

It works when I use a command in the parent directory and just sync the folders, but why it does not work this way from within the folder?

Comment: What if you use `rsync -avze ssh user@server:src/app/* ..`?

Comment: produces the same problem....